# Relative URL as hostname in Nock

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, nock, isomorphic-fetch-api

I need to mock client side HTTP requests. I'm using `isomorphic-fetch` in the client side and I'm using `mocha` and `nock` for testing and mocking. All my client requests are based on relative path. Due to this I'm unable to provide host name for the `nock`. Is there a work around.

Client side:

```
fetch('/foo') //hostname: http://localhost:8080
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Test suite

```
nock('/')
.get('/foo')
.reply(200, {data: "hello"})
```

This is failing as I'm not giving the proper hostname for the `nock`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround for this. Have a `_ajax-setup.js` in your test folder

```
import $ from 'jquery'

$(document).ajaxSend((event, jqxhr, settings) => {
  settings.url = 'http://0.0.0.0' + settings.url;
})
```

The thing to note is that this file has to run **First** and **Only Once**. Having it as a file runs only once and `_` before it makes it alphabetically first.

Later you can test your code with

```
nock('http://0.0.0.0')
.get('/foo')
.reply(200, {data: "hello"})
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested: In my react/webpack project I solved this by prepending the fetch url with 'http://localhost' when `NODE_ENV` is set to `'test'`.

example:

```
const testing = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';
const apiUrl = `${testing ? 'http://localhost' : ''}/api`;

function getStuffFromApi() {
  return fetch(apiUrl, ...)
}
```

This way, in my test I can always use nock like so:

```
nock('http://localhost')
  .get('/api')
  .reply(200, {data: 'hello'})
```

**NOTE**: When running my tests, NODE_ENV gets set to 'test'

Comment: Please provide code examples to illustrate the usage.

Answer (score 4):

For axios I added following to my test file. This helped overcome this limitation.

```
    axios.defaults.baseURL='http://localhost:4000/';
```

Please note that this is a global variable.
With this the actual code can live with relative URL and there is no need to check testing flag in it.

Answer (score 2):

I just asked a similar question on Nock's repository. Apparently this is not supported: https://github.com/pgte/nock/issues/431

Answer (score 2):

kudresov's reply to [liorbauer's issue](https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/431) describes a Jest-specific workaround.

> Put this into __mocks__/isomorphic-fetch.js:

```
const fetch = require.requireActual('isomorphic-fetch');

module.exports = (url, config) => {
  return fetch('https://localhost' + url, config);
};
```

> Jest then automatically replaces all requires (or imports) for this node module.
>
> In other test frameworks you could use something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

Comment: Easily the best solution for isomorphic-fetch.